# Trying to create a form with 2 "quantity" selectors using html, javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a quantity selector like what you would find in a grocery store website or in most e-commerce sites. (One with  +1 and -1 buttons)  I can make the first selector work but can't seem to get the second one to.

Here's the code and HTML I have so far:

```js
function addNum1() {
    var newValue = Number(ordernow.firstvalue.value);
    newValue +=1;
    ordernow.firstvalue.value = newValue;   
}

function minusNum1() {
    var subNum = Number(ordernow.firstvalue.value); 
    if (subNum > 0) {
    subNum -= 1;
    ordernow.firstvalue.value = subNum;
    } 
}
function addNum2() {
    var newValue = Number(ordernow.firstvalue2.value);
    newValue2 +=1;
    ordernow.firstvalue2.value = newValue2; 
}

function minusNum2() {
    var subNum2 = Number(ordernow.firstvalue2.value); 
    if (subNum2 > 0) {
    subNum2 -= 1;
    ordernow.firstvalue2.value = subNum2;
    } 
};
```

```html
<body>
  <div class=container>
    <form name="orderup" id="ordernow">
      <p> Chicken &nbsp &nbsp $4.57</p>
      Quantity<input type="button" id="firstminus" value="- 1"      onclick="minusNum1()"/>
      <input type="text" id="firstvalue" value="0"/>  
      <input type="button" id="firstadd" value="+1" onclick="addNum1()"/>
      <p> Beef &nbsp &nbsp $3.32</p>
      Quantity<input type="button" id="firstminus2" value="- 1" onclick="minusNum2()"/>
      <input type="text" id="firstvalue2" value="0"/>  
      <input type="button" id="firstadd2" value="+1" onclick="addNum2()"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or a codepen or etc., and add a link to it in your question.  What you have in your question is incomplete and invalid.

Comment: Or an SO code snippet. It's coming...Wait for the edit approval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open your browser's development tools the console should show an error message. On Chrome I get:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: newValue2 is not defined`

This is because `addNum2()` declares *newValue* but then uses *newValue2* on the next line.

```
function addNum2() {
    var newValue = Number(ordernow.firstvalue2.value);
    newValue2 +=1;
    ordernow.firstvalue2.value = newValue2; 
}
```

var **newValue** = Number(ordernow.firstvalue2.value);
**newValue2** +=1;

You can use the same var name because you are in a different function scope.
Fix:

```
function addNum2() {
    var newValue = Number(ordernow.firstvalue2.value);
    newValue +=1;
    ordernow.firstvalue2.value = newValue; 
}
```

Always check for error messages in the console and run your javascript in the debugger when something is "mysteriously" not working.